# PHP File Upload Not Working Properly

Tags: php, mysql, file, upload

I am trying to update a record in a database. The code is meant to allow users to update an entry on a website with the option to edit the image as well. When I was initially testing this code it worked with no issues. When they selected an image it would update the image, and when they did not select an image it would not include the image in the updating. When I moved this code to the page that it needs to be on it is no longer working. It is always reading it as if the user has not selected an image to upload. The only thing that has changed between the test code and this code is the names in the database, and the addition of mysql_real_escape_string() for the variables $title and $description.

Here is the PHP code that is not working for me:

```
<?php
require_once ("connect.php");
if (isset($_POST['description'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $title = mysql_real_escape_string($title);
    $description = mysql_real_escape_string($description);
    $target = "../images/contests/";
    $target = $target.basename( $_FILES['image']['name']);
    $ok=1;

    if($_FILES['image']['name'] == "") {
        $query = "UPDATE tbl_contests SET contests_title='$title', contests_description='$description' WHERE contests_id='$id'";
        $result = mysql_query ($query);
            if ($result) {
            header ("Location: contests.php?=noimage");
            exit ();
        } else {
            header ("Location: contests.php?=error");
            exit ();
        }
    } else {
        if ($ok==0){
            header("Location: contests.php?=error");
        } else {
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)){
                echo "<p>Your upload was sucessful.</p>";
                $query = "UPDATE tbl_contests SET contests_title='$title', contests_description='$description', contests_image='$target' WHERE contests_id='$id'";
                $result = mysql_query ($query);
                if ($result) {
                    header ("Location: contests.php?=image");
                    exit ();
                } else {
                    header ("Location: contests.php?=error");
                    exit ();
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
?>
```

Here is the form pertaining to the above code:

```
<?php
    $postnum = $_GET['id'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_contests WHERE contests_id=".$postnum;
    $result= mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $path = "../images/contests/";
    ?>

    <form action="update-past.php?id=<?php print $row[contests_id]; ?>" method="post" id="updatepast">
    <br /><label>Title:</label> <p><input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="input" value="<?php print $row[contests_title]; ?>" /></p>
    <?php if ($row['contests_image'] == !null) { ?>
    <p><img src="<?php print $path.$row['contests_image']; ?>" width="425" height="500" /></p>
    <br /><label>Edit Image: (Optional)</label> <p><input name="image" type="file" id="image" class="file" size="50" /></p>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><label>Add Image: (Optional)</label> <p><input name="image" type="file" id="image" class="file" size="50" /></p>
    <?php } ?>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><label>Description:</label><p><textarea name="description" cols="85" id="description" class="contentinput" rows="10"><?php print $row[contests_description]; ?></textarea></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" id="button" value="Edit" /></p>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to the form: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Here's some reading on form content types: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2